# For this matrix, for which $a$ will be the eigenvector $(1,-1,a)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

\begin{pmatrix} 1&-1&0 \\ -3&1&1 \\ -4&2&a \end{pmatrix}

$ii.$ Does it have an eigenvector in the form of $(0,b,a)$, where $b \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary?

Well, I have calculated the characteristic polynomial, which will be $2-2a \implies 2(1-a)=0$.
How can I continue?

Comment: One question,why the characteristic polynomial is $2-2a$?

Comment: Just to check - you are premultiplying by row vectors rather than post multiplying by column vectors - is that correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(1,-1, a)$ is an eigenvector.

$\pmatrix{1 &-1&0\\-3&1&1\\-4&2&a}\pmatrix{1\\-1\\a} = \lambda \pmatrix{1\\-1\\a}\\
\pmatrix{2\\-4+2a\\-6+a^2} = \lambda \pmatrix{1\\-1\\a}$

$2 = \lambda\\
-4 + 2a = -2\\
-6 + a^2  = 2a$

There is no $a$

Comment: do I have to do the same with the $ii$ question?

Comment: Looks like it...

Comment: for $ii$ I get that $\pmatrix{1 &-1&0\\-3&1&1\\-4&2&a}\pmatrix{0\\b\\a} = \lambda \pmatrix{0\\b\\a}\\
\pmatrix{-b\\b+a\\2b+a^2} = \lambda \pmatrix{0\\b\\a}$

Comment: so will be $a=b=0$?

Comment: The 0 vector is not an eigenvector.  So again no such vector exists.

Answer (score 3):

I would try multiplying your prospective eigenvector by the matrix and seeing what emerges from that - an eigenvector will get sent to a multiple of itself.

Comment: as a result of the multiplication I get $(-4a+4,2a-2,a^2-1)$

Comment: @Zauberkerl And what are the conditions for that to be a scalar multiple of the original vector? Can you see a common factor in the terms of the vector you have computed?

Comment: do you mean that I have to check the linear equation system $-4a+4 = 1,2a-2=-1,a^2-1=a$?

Comment: You need $\lambda (1,-1,a)= (-4a+4, 2a-2, a^2-1)$ but if you spot a factor on the left-hand side it will be easy.